# Reduce subdivision quality in viewport on multiple objects at once

Tags: workflow, subdivision-surface, optimization

I increased the viewport quality on my subdivision but forgot to reduce it after finishing the model and have since duplicated the model like 60 times, is there a way to turn down the viewport quality on all of them at once since it happened on two separate models and I'd rather not go through 120+ objects reducing the quality manually but blender is starting to lag from the massive amounts of geometry it's having to render in real-time.

Comment: Select all and use Ctrl + the wanted amount (the numeric keys from the keybord main part).

Comment: Thanks, That Worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the *Simplify* function.

You can set *Max Subdivision* for Viewport or Render in your whole scene.
*Render Tab > Simplify > Viewport*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL-L. I read it in another post, but can't paste the link because it will says I can only write it as a comment, and I don't have comment access yetm